# Adding text values to a HTML/JQuery Slider bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I have a slider bar on the following price calculator page:

http://outsource-plus.co.uk/test2.html

The HTML code for the slider is as follows:

```
<div class="sub-option o-3 o-slider" data-type="slider">
<div class="well">
<p><strong>Slider: </strong></p>
<input class="i-slider" type="number" id="sl_1" name="sl_1" data-slider="true" value="2" min="0" max="20" step="2" data-cost="3"/><span class="staticPrice"><span class="hypen"> - </span>$3 AUD per unit</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Instead of the values 0,2,4,6,8 etc. I would like to enter time/text value such as 1 day, 2 days, 3to5 days and etc.

Is this possible?

Comment: I would think that its possible.  You just need to grab the value and then you can add whatever you want after.. For example instead of `step="2"` you could do `step="1"` and then grab the value from the slide and prepend it to the string ' days`... From what you have provided its hard to understand what you want..  But maybe if you could clarify and include a http://jsfiddle.net/ demonstrating your code that might help.

Comment: Ok forget about the step, instead of 0,2,4,6,8. I would like 0 days, 2 days, 4 days etc. basically the values to be text values.

Comment: Can you show your jQuery that is setting the `price-tag`?

Comment: Basically in the input class can i change the type fucntion to anything apart form number? how would this work?

Comment: I don't really understand.. You should be fine with numbers.. In java script it's really easy to convert a number to a string you just need to join it with a string.  What kind of slider are you using?  Here is a simple example http://jsfiddle.net/WvAeg/